# Help needed to write a comparator for my job interview code sample

Tags: java, comparator

I need help to write a comparator :-

I want this output :-

```
Martin Joseph Male 4/2/1979 Green 
Ramya  Patil  Female 5/4/2009 Red
Don    kelly  Male   5/6/1986 Yellow
Van    Shinde female 3/4/1984 Green
```

But i am getting the following output :-

```
Output 1:
 Van    Shinde female 3/4/1984 Green
 Don    kelly  Male   5/6/1986 Yellow
 Ramya  Patil  Female 5/4/2009 Red
 Martin Joseph Male 4/2/1979 Green
```

how do i sort on last name keeping  the order of the list intact .. i mean i want to output female first sorting on last name and then male sorted on last name ... please help me guys ..

this is the comparator i am using after i use the gender comparator :-

```
public class LastNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {


public int compare(Person name_one, Person name_two) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(name_one.getGender().equals(name_two.getGender())){
            return name_one.getLast_name().compareTo(name_two.getLast_name());

        }else{
        return name_one.getLast_name().compareTo(name_two.getLast_name());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If anything, it looks like your getLast_name() would be the culprit.

Comment: At a guess, `getLast_name` is returning gender. (Probably autogenerated.)

Comment: it seems like it may be unethical to be getting help for a job interview code sample...unless the potential employer is aware you are getting help.

Comment: Hopefully the interviewer reads SO too...

Comment: Your `if` and `else` results are same. Wondering why you need a condition anyway??

Comment: This post is clearly for help on a code sample for a particular company's application process. Just know that before giving rivlinp too much help :)

Comment: Hmm. I didn't realise that when I answered the question :/

Comment: Funnily enough, I ask people who interview with me if they have an account on SO.  If I saw one of my questions come up there with a thoughtful back and forth with a clearly knowledgeable OP, I would tend to think favorably of them.  Unfortunately, this question doesn't give a very good impression when it comes to the OP....

Answer (score 4):

```
public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
  int ret = a.getGender().compareTo(b.getGender());
  if (ret == 0) {
    ret = a.getLastName().compareTo(b.getLastName());
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I read the code in your OP I see that you're always returning the result of comparing by the last name:

```
If genders are equal
  then compare last names
  else compare last names
```

However that doesn't much the experimental results which you say you're getting; so as well as modifying your code to match Cletus' suggestion, maybe something else is wrong with your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cletus' solution is probably the most appropriate here, but if you want to take it a little further...

`LastNameComparator` is rather misleadingly named, since it actually compares on gender as well as last name. It might be less ambiguous to split this functionality into two separate `Comparators`:

```
class GenderComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.getGender().compareTo(b.getGender());
    }
}

class LastNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.getLastName().compareTo(b.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Then, combine the functionality in a 'custom' `Comparator`:

```
Comparator<Person> genderThenLastNameComparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
    public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
        int result = new GenderComparator().compare(a, b);
        return result == 0 ? new LastNameComparator().compare(a, b) : result;
    }
}
```

It's more complicated, but more flexible and reusable. (Which may or may not be justified for such a simple case.)

Comment: if you like that, the apache commons has built-in comparator chaining: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/cli2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli2/util/Comparators.html

Comment: So the relevant code for the commons `Comparators` class would be `Comparator<Person> c = Comparators.chain(new GenderComparator(), new LastNameComparator());`. Looks pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to cletus's answer, here's a version using a [`CompareToBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) (from Apache Commons Lang):

```
public int compare(Person lhs, Person rhs) {
    return new CompareToBuilder()
            .append(lhs.getGender(), rhs.getGender())
            .append(lhs.getLastName(), rhs.getLastName())
            .toComparison();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively simple:

here are the rules you specified:

- females before males
- names sorted in last name ascending

you do something like this:

```
// if the genders are not equal, return <0 if this object's gender is female
// else 
//    return lastName.compareTo( obj.lastName );
```

that's all you need to implement this comparator...

then when you want to sort it, use the collections framework sort!

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
                            Comparator<? super T> c)
```

This is a stable sort too...which is awesome.  If you answer it this way I'm sure you'll get the job.